# Using bootstrap cards as a hyperlink

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap card Which is used as a link.

Trying to wrap it with `<a>` changes all of the styling of the card.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <div class="card" style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Normal card</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

<a href="">
  <div class="card" style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Wrapped with a tag</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</a>
```

How should I wrap the card in order to preserve its looks and use it as a link?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Its because `<a>` tags has a default blue color from user agent browser.  Try to add a class to the link and set `color:inherit` to that class

```css
a.custom-card,
a.custom-card:hover {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card" style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Normal card</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="" class="custom-card">
  <div class="card" style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Wrapped with a tag</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: According to w3schools, an inline element that has been converted to a block element cannot contain block elements inside it. Note on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp. With that in mind, is it advisable to have an anchor tag for a card which would probably contain block elements such as <p> inside it

Answer (score 105):

If you are using Bootstrap 4.3 you don't have to wrap card with `<a>` tag, but instead put it inside `card-body`, and use `stretched-link` class. This is much cleaner way.

Visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/stretched-link/ for more details.

If you can't use Bootstrap 4.3 this is styling for `stretched-link` class:

```
.stretched-link::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    content: "";
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Here is the example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card" style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Normal card</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card" style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Alternative</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="stretched-link"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best answer for Bootstrap 4.3, way easier than all other alternatives!

Comment: Best answer. Nothing else needed.

Comment: I was using `.stretched-link` but I needed to switch to Bootstrap 4.3. Thanks.

Comment: But this does not work without the href attribute. If you use a framwork like Angular and implement clicks via binding, the href is a problem

Comment: Works for Patternfly v3 cards if you implement stretched-link class in your css and put it on your link inside card's div.

Comment: How is that "cleaner" than having the link directly being used at the level of the block (as @Turnip suggests)? According to me it would be much more semantic and would even work if CSS isn't loaded. What element being clicked would follow a link is *meaning*, not display.

Comment: Bootstrap 5.0: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/stretched-link/

Answer (score 16):

Instead of wrapping the `.card` in a `<a>`, you could use a `<a>` as the card element instead of a `<div>`.

This will allow you to easily override the CSS to remove the default `<a>` styles:

```css
a.card,
a.card:hover {
  color: #212529;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card" style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Normal card</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="card" style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Wrapped with a tag</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This works for me. For me, wrapping the `.card div` IN an `<a>` element broke some styling of the card (it seemed to override `d-flex align-items-stretch`applied to the containing column `<div>`. This method does not do that.

Answer (score 10):

Very simple with [Stretched link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/stretched-link/)

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card with stretched link</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

bootstrap make it easy with [Stretched link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/stretched-link/)

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card with stretched link</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put `text-dark` utility class to the element to have the same appearance.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a href="">
  <div class="card text-dark" style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=318%C3%97180&w=318&h=180" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Wrapped with a tag</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Slight problem: If you remove "display: inline-block" there is a underline on hover...

Answer (score -1):

Try to add Display: Block to the link itself. Use your browsers Developer Tools (F12) and hover over the link to see if you need to add Height:auto perhaps.

Comment: Why would this help?

Comment: This will force the link to wrap around multiple elements.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it with this trick. You can specify the  color whatever you like and put a 00 at the end of the color code to make it transparent this way you make the  style invisible. e.g.

```
<a href="" style="color: #83577500; ">
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add "cursor: pointer;" to your style

Comment: First of all, it's not a valid answer to the question. Then, you're answering question that is more than 2 years old and already have an accepted answer.

Comment: This answer is ... I guess you test 'how it works' - if you can (not sure) - delete this answer for your test. It could be a comment, not an answer - even if it would be brilliant it doesn't explain anything