# Make Bootstrap cards clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a page with several bootstrap cards and if you hover over the card the zoom effect appears. Now I want to make the whole card clickable. That means, when you hover over the card (courser: pointer) you should be able to click and get to another page. There might be a possibility to stretch an a-tag? OR is there something else. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey Julian, I suggest posting your code so we can help you with your specific situation. You can chop out just the parts that matter and post in a code block in your question! Welcome!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "stretch an a tag", but generally speaking, you can put anything you want inside it. Have you actually tried putting your card inside an a tag?

Comment: Possibly this question has an answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554070/using-bootstrap-cards-as-a-hyperlink

Comment: I'm surprised that this hasn't been asked on SO before (that I can find). I would suggest making it more general though (not just specific to bootstrap), because what you're asking for could be referenced just in html and javascript. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thx to all for the warm welcom and the really quick answers. Nxxt time ill definitly will post the code, thx for the advice :) the solutions with the a tag wrapped around my cards seems woking. First i need to undo the wrongly styled text because of the atag and then i connect an actual ref. But seems rly good so far. Thank you all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("click").onclick = () => {
  console.log('clicked')
  document.getElementById("click").textContent = "click me (clicked)"
  // if you want to redirect ( remove the "//" in the next line ):
  // window.location.href = "http://example.com"
}
```

```html
<span id="click">click me</span>
```

There's also other ways to do the Javascript such as:

```js
document.getElementById("click").addEventListener('click', () => {
  //lines 2-5 from above
})
```

I do, however, recommend that if you just want to take the user to a new page that you wrap the whole thing in an `<a>` tag. Why? Sometimes the user has javascript disabled, plus most search engines will not see this as a link if you add it with JavaScript. As a general rule that I use with HTML, you should only use JavaScript when needed. (And I think most others will probably agree).